# Inserting Chinese characters in AppleScript

Tags: macos, unicode, applescript

How can I insert text from Chinese characters using AppleScript? All my attempts end with "aaaa aaaaaa aaaaaaa", I tried to find some information about using Unicode, but I failed. 
I also tried to change the system language. This relatively helped, AppleScript actually started inserting hieroglyphs, but in the final result it didn't help, because only 1 hieroglyph was printed due to auto-correction and help in typing.

[image]

Comment: You could try using this method instead, e.g.: `set the clipboard to "在AppleScript中插入中文字符"` and then after setting focus where you want it, use: `tell application "System Events" to keystroke "v" using command down`, then you should have your Chinese characters inserted where you wanted them.

Comment: Yes, I think in the same direction and have already implemented this method. It works, but I would still like to find a more reliable solution if possible. @user3439894

Comment: Insert Chinese text into a specific application, or any application ?  And would it be a specific phrase, or could it be any phrase ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm making some guesses about what you're trying to do but this should allow for inserting text into a document (or the clipboard). I use TextEdit but it should work with any app that allows you to work similarly with text. In my example, I simply use your text as is, but you could get that text from the clipboard or another document (as provided for in the comments).

```
set srcIdeo to "你好，朋友！你好嗎？测试消息。" -- text taken from screen shot
--set srcIdeo to the clipboard
tell application "TextEdit"

    -- list all Chinese characters to begin with
    -- set srcIdeo to every character of document "sourceIdeo.txt"
    set allChar to every character of srcIdeo

    -- list unicode id of allChar
    set chList to {}
    repeat with i in allChar
        copy id of i to end of chList
    end repeat
end tell

-- list all Chinese characters to insert into text (doesn't work inside TextEdit tell block)
set chTx to ""
repeat with ch in chList
    character id ch
    set chTx to chTx & character id ch
end repeat
-- set the clipboard to chTx

-- insert into text 
tell application "TextEdit" to set last paragraph of front document to chTx
--tell application "TextEdit" to set last paragraph of front document to the clipboard

(*
Example
allChar {"你", "好", "，", "朋", "友", "！", "你", "好", "嗎", "？", "测", "试", "消", "息", "。"}
chList {20320, 22909, 65292, 26379, 21451, 65281, 20320, 22909, 21966, 65311, 27979, 35797, 28040, 24687, 12290}
chTx "你好，朋友！你好嗎？测试消息。"
*)
```

Essentially, applescript uses a 16-bit dec (base10) code to represent the unicode 4-digit hex code. So for the first character '你', which the character viewer describes as below, the code U+4F60 translates to '20320' — which turns out to be a straight conversion from the hex to decimal. As an aside, it handles RGB colour codes in a similar manner.

> CJK UNIFIED IDEOGRAPH-4F60 
>   Unicode: U+4F60, UTF-8: E4 BD A0

In applescript…

```
id of "你"
character id 20320
```

From the *AppleScript Language Guide*, 124
Class Reference > text > Properties of text objects
https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_classes.html

Answer (score 0):

Short answer, we can input non-ASCII characters with the clipboard:

```
tell application "System Events"
    set textBuffer to "你好吗，朋友！"
    repeat with i from 1 to count characters of textBuffer
        set the clipboard to (character i of textBuffer)
        delay 0.05
        keystroke "v" using command down
    end repeat
end tell
```